# AWS Amplify authorization based on db field value or relationship

Tags: graphql, authorization, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I am creating a webapp with Amplify ( GraphQL api ) and Quasar Framework.

Using Amazon Cognito for authentication.

Lets say the db has these entities:
A User who has his own profile where he can manage his own data, and even make it public if he turns the 'public' boolean field to true.

An Organization who have todos etc.

A User can become an Employee of one ( or maybe more ) organization(s) and should be able to manage for example the todos that belong to the organization where he became an employee.

I am stuck at figuring out how to add authorization rules to make this happen.

Owner authorization should be suitable for the user profile, but even there its not clear how to setup a rule that makes the profile public if the user sets the 'public' boolean field setting to true in his profile.

For example:

```
type Todo @model @searchable @auth(rules: [{allow: owner, operations: [read, create, update, delete]}]) {
  id: ID!
  Title: String!
  Description: String
}
```

This way if a user logs in he can manage and list his own todos, but how can I allow him to view and manage todos that belong to an organization where he is an employee ( employee would be a join table which connects the user and the organization )?

Answer (score 1):

I have undertaken some research on this issue, and although it is far from complete, I would like to share it.

1. Despite [amplify docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/auth#combining-multiple-authorization-types) say, that there is possibility to combine multiple autorization types, they don't specify explicitly, that you can't combine them in one request (my be, it's evident for them, but not for novice like me).
2. When you configure your AppSync GraphQL API with `amplify update api`, you choose default authorization type. All subsequent requests from your front  by `await API.graphql()` will use this default unless you explicitly specify different type like this `await API.graphql(Object.assign(graphqlOperation(listTodos),{authMode: auth_mode}))`, where `auth_mode` can take one of next values: `"API_KEY", "AWS_IAM", "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS"` and `"OPENID_CONNECT"`.
3. There are two "true" public authorization types in Amplify - `"API_KEY"` and `"AWS_IAM"`. To activate any of them (or both), you should do something like that:

```
    type Todo @model   
     @auth(rules: [
        { allow: public },
        { allow: public, provider: iam},
        ])
        {
          id: ID!
          name: String!
          description: String
          owner: String
          editors: [String]
          entity: String
        }
```

4. `{ allow: public }` stands for `"API_KEY"`, `{ allow: public, provider: iam}` - for `"AWS_IAM"`.
5. For `"API_KEY"`to work propery you should configure API KEY (for ex - with `amplify update api`). For `"AWS_IAM"` you should configure Cognito and enable unauthenticated identities in Cognito Identity Pool.
6. After that, any request without prior user sign-in of the form `await API.graphql(Object.assign(graphqlOperation(listTodos),{authMode: auth_mode}))` with `auth_mode=API_KEY` or `auth_mode=AWS_IAM` will succeed (also updateTodo, createTodo and deleteTodo).
7. In either case you can't implement your workflow with public field, enabled by user, "out of the box", because permission evaluation get accomplished **prior** to any database info gets available. For ex, IAM authorization uses unauthenticated role policy, generated for you by `amplify update api`. You can see it in your AWS console in IAM service.
8. To partially implement your private/public workflow I can suggest to use so called dynamic group authorization(We assume "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS" auth mode). In that case you implement "public" group in your Cognito User Pool and make any user member of this group (you can automate this by using post signUp hooks).
9. Your @auth could be something like that

```
    type Todo @model   
     @auth(rules: [
        { allow: owner },
        { allow: groups, groupsField: "groupsCanAccess", operations: [read] },
        ])
        {
          id: ID!
          name: String!
          description: String
          owner: String
          editors: [String]
          entity: String
          groupsCanAccess: [String]
        }
```

10. When your user decides that it's time to go public, she request updateTodo with `groupsCanAccess` set to `public`. As  you can see, this is partial solution because to read todos your "public" user should be registered.
11. To partially implement your employee-organization workflow I could suggest next approach (We again assume "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS"):

```
  type User @model 
  @auth( rules: [
  { allow: owner },
  { allow: groups, groupsField: "groupsCanAccess", operations: [read] },
  {allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"] }  
      ]) {
      id: ID!
      owner: String! @auth(rules[{allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"] }]) 
      groupsCanAccess:[String] 
      @auth(rules[{allow: owner},{allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"] }])
      todo: [Todo] @connection(keyName: "byUser", fields: ["owner"])

  type Todo @model 
   (queries: null)
   @auth ({allow: owner, operations[delete]})
   @key [(name: "byUser", fields: ["owner", "description"])
      {
        id: ID!
        name: String!
        description: String
        owner: String! @auth(rules[{allow: owner}])
      }
```

12. Here everybody can create, update and read Todo, but read operation is possible only through User (queries: null), so nobody can get particular id to update particular Todo except owner. There is though some little possibility that someone can guess this id and it's drawback of this approach. It's impossible to create Todo without owner (exclamation sign on field), and nobody can create Todo but owner (nobody can alter owner field but owner). Note that operations[delete] is important, because without that nobody can query Todo through User ( {allow: owner} equivalent to {allow: owner, operations[create,update,read,delete]}).
13. Owner can do everything with User, but she can't create or delete User because she can't alter owner field protected by perfield @auth directive
14. Admins can create User and set owner to particular user.
15. Admins and owner can alter groupsCanAccess field. Every element in this array corresponds to some organization. When Admins or owner add some organization, every member of this group gains access to this User and to all of her Todos through this User. Drawback - owner can forbid access granted by Admins. Because Todos aren't protected from update - every group member can alter Todos of particular User.
16. Operations of adding Cognito User Pool user to group performed by admins and are out of scope of this document. Drawback - only 300 Groups per Cognito Pool.
17. And last - you of course have option to manually adjust resolvers, automatically generated by Amplify. You may for ex use "AWS_IAM" and organize owner check by analyzing $context.identity.cognitoIdentityId inside your rezolver mapping template. As you know - there is one-to-one correspondence between this Cognito Identity Pool paramener and user from User Pool. It's especially convinient when you need to store public and owner's Todos (there is some unique per Identity Pool cognitoIdentityId corresponding to unauthenticated user).

Answer (score 0):

Have exact the same problem
My hopefully temporarily solution is : Adding a lamdaFunction : myResolver and adding this function to the graqphl-schema. in that function a can do all the filtering thru the databaseClient Class

the schema

```
 type Query {
  myqueryresolver(params: String): String @function (name: "myqueryresolver-${env}")
}
```

Now You define a lamda (In my case I use a generic form ....) in which you perform all the non standard queries.

You call this function :

```
const dataObj = await API.graphql(
    {
      query: myqueryresolver,
      variables:  {"params": JSON.stringify(params)} 
    }
  );
```

All the public access goes thru this function call.
Additional hint
You can run it locally with "amplify mock" and you can see all the output from your console.log locally - no need to deploy during dev.